# Change [exec] label in output for Ant <exec> task

Tags: ant, exec, parallel-processing, echo

I am using Ant's `<parallel>` task to perform multiple simultaneous targets that use `<exec>` tasks, but it's difficult to read the output because it is interleaved. Is there any way to change the `[exec]` label that appears before each line of output to use the command or target name?

For example, while running `pdepend` and `phpcpd` I would like to change `[exec]` to `[pdepend]` and `[phpcpd]`:

```
pdepend:
    [exec] PHP_Depend 0.10.5 by Manuel Pichler
    [exec] 

phpcpd:
    [exec] Parsing source files:
    [exec] phpcpd 1.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.
    [exec] 
    [exec] ............................................................    60
    [exec] Found 26 exact clones with 640 duplicated lines in 28 files:
    [exec] 
    [exec]   - application/modules/controllers/IndexController.php:16-31
    [exec] ............................................................   120
    [exec]     application/modules/controllers/ErrorController.php:15-30
    [exec] 
    [exec]   - application/modules/controllers/PhotosController.php:24-33
    [exec] ............................................................   180
    [exec] ............................................................   240
```

becomes

```
pdepend:
 [pdepend] PHP_Depend 0.10.5 by Manuel Pichler
 [pdepend] 

phpcpd:
  [phpcpd] Parsing source files:
  [phpcpd] phpcpd 1.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.
  [phpcpd] 
 [pdepend] ............................................................    60
  [phpcpd] Found 26 exact clones with 640 duplicated lines in 28 files:
  [phpcpd] 
  [phpcpd]   - application/modules/controllers/IndexController.php:16-31
 [pdepend] ............................................................   120
  [phpcpd]     application/modules/controllers/ErrorController.php:15-30
  [phpcpd] 
  [phpcpd]   - application/modules/controllers/PhotosController.php:24-33
 [pdepend] ............................................................   180
 [pdepend] ............................................................   240
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but it's an excellent feature request.

Comment: @Alexander - I'll add it to Ant's tracker if I don't get a positive answer in a day or two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `taskname` attribute on the `exec` task? I'll double check in a couple of hours and confirm.

**Update:**
Yep, `taskname` does the trick. e.g.,

```
<exec executable="phpcpd" taskname="phpcpd">
    ...
</exec>
```

From [Common Attributes of all Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/common.html):

> `taskname`: A different name for this task instance - will show up in the logging output.

Comment: I've never heard of the `taskname` attribute, and the only reference to it in the Ant documentation that I could find is when talking about how to write a task, i.e. the general form of a task is `<taskname attributes>...</taskname>`. *But* it works!

Comment: I've never found much documentation for it either. It doesn't just apply to `exec` tasks either. You can use it on all sorts of tasks, most importantly `echo`.

Comment: Found the documentation for `taskname` at  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/common.html